# Split string by tab and ignore tab in multi double quotes

Tags: java, regex

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "hi   ravi    \"how   are you\"   when    are you coming";
    String regex = "\"([^\"]*)\"|(\\S+)";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        if (m.group(1) != null) {
            System.out.println("Quoted [" + m.group(1) + "]");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Plain [" + m.group(0) + "]");
        }
    }
    // getSplits(text);
}
```

Output:

> Plain [hi]
>   Plain [ravi]
>   Quoted [how are you]
>   Plain [when]
>   Plain [are]
>   Plain [you]
>   Plain [coming]

Above code is working fine if the given text has only one single quotation. Can any one help me how to get below output with below input:

```
text = "hi  ravi    \"\"how are\"   you\"   when    are you coming";
```

Expected Output:

> Plain [hi]
>   Plain [ravi]
>   Quoted ["how are" you]
>   Plain [when]
>   Plain [are]
>   Plain [you]
>   Plain [coming]

Comment: text="hi ravi \"\"how are\" you\" when are you coming"; 
Expected Output: 
Plain [hi] 
Plain [ravi]Quoted ["how are" you] 
Plain [when] 
Plain [are] 
Plain [you] 
Plain [coming]

Comment: From where are you getting this kind of input? Even if quotes are nested at least inner quotes should be escaped

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/lT6hB7/2) suit for your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Following regex works for your example input/output. You will have to give a more detailed description of the expected result, as this might not be what you were expecting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "hi  ravi    \"\"how are\"   you\"   when    are you coming";
    String regex = "(\".+\")|(\\S+)";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

    while (m.find()) {
        if (m.group(1) != null) {
            System.out.println("Quoted [" + m.group(1) + "]");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Plain [" + m.group(0) + "]");
        }
    }
    // getSplits(text);
}
```

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
[\t]+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

See the [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/jH1iT2/2)